# Is there a way or code to duplicate categories on opencart?

Tags: duplicates, opencart, categories

is there a way to duplicate a category with filters? Any code to do this? 
Thanks for your help

Comment: I think it's important that you outline the version of Opencart that you're using and some of the sample code that you've worked on thus far. You're far more likely to get a response

Comment: ^ What Daniel said - also, have a look at the marketplace to see if there's something that already does what you want: https://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=marketplace/extension&filter_search=copy%20category

Comment: Hello, my opencart version is 3.0.2. I know there's an extension but its too expensive for this.